# Swift3: Unable to delete rows in a section

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have attempted several possible ways that a selected cell is deleted, but it crashes everytime. I picked some code from other stackoverflow post, but it just failed.

I have created an alphabetic section set of arrays;

```
sections = [
        Section(title: "A", word: []),
        Section(title: "B", word: []),
        Section(title: "C", word: []),
        Section(title: "D", word: []),
        Section(title: "E", word: []),
        Section(title: "F", word: []),
        Section(title: "G", word: []),
        Section(title: "H", word: []),
        Section(title: "I", word: []),
        Section(title: "J", word: []),
        Section(title: "K", word: []),
        Section(title: "L", word: []),
        Section(title: "M", word: []),
        Section(title: "N", word: []),
        Section(title: "O", word: []),
        Section(title: "P", word: []),
        Section(title: "Q", word: []),
        Section(title: "R", word: []),
        Section(title: "S", word: []),
        Section(title: "T", word: []),
        Section(title: "U", word: []),
        Section(title: "V", word: []),
        Section(title: "W", word: []),
        Section(title: "X", word: []),
        Section(title: "Y", word: []),
        Section(title: "Z", word: [])
    ]
```

Then, I add some element into the `word[]`. For example, I add "sunny", it is automatically added into S section. After a `UITableView` is loaded and when I select the cell to delete, it get crashes saying

> reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of
>   sections contained in the table view after the update (26) must be
>   equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the
>   update (26), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted
>   (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'

Here is what I did in `editingStyle` func:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source

        tableView.beginUpdates()

        let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
        indexSet.add(indexPath.section)
        tableView.deleteSections(sections[indexPath.section].words[indexPath.row] as IndexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)

        tableView.endUpdates()

    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have to delete the entry from your `sections` array before you delete the section from the table.

Comment: How do I do? Your code is so helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I had implemented a little scenario with your problem, and this is what i had done

```
import UIKit

class Section
{
    var title: String  = ""
    var words: [String] = []

    init(title:String,word:[String]) {
        self.title = title
        self.words = word
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var testTableView: UITableView!

    var sections : [Section] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        sections = [
            Section(title: "A", word: ["Avena"]),
            Section(title: "B", word: []),
            Section(title: "C", word: []),
            Section(title: "D", word: []),
            Section(title: "E", word: []),
            Section(title: "F", word: []),
            Section(title: "G", word: []),
            Section(title: "H", word: []),
            Section(title: "I", word: []),
            Section(title: "J", word: []),
            Section(title: "K", word: []),
            Section(title: "L", word: []),
            Section(title: "M", word: []),
            Section(title: "N", word: []),
            Section(title: "O", word: []),
            Section(title: "P", word: []),
            Section(title: "Q", word: []),
            Section(title: "R", word: []),
            Section(title: "S", word: ["Susto"]),
            Section(title: "T", word: []),
            Section(title: "U", word: []),
            Section(title: "V", word: []),
            Section(title: "W", word: []),
            Section(title: "X", word: []),
            Section(title: "Y", word: []),
            Section(title: "Z", word: [])
        ]

        self.testTableView.delegate = self
        self.testTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.sections[section].words.count
    }


    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testCell", for: indexPath) as! TestTableViewCell
        cell.lblWordText.text = self.sections[indexPath.section].words[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
       return self.sections.count
    }


    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
    {
        return self.sections[section].title
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source

            tableView.beginUpdates()

            let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
            indexSet.add(indexPath.section)

            //let indexSet = sections[indexPath.section].words[indexPath.row] as IndexSet
            //sections.remove(at: indexPath.section)
            sections[indexPath.section].words.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            //tableView.deleteSections(indexSet, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

            tableView.endUpdates()

        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

I hope this helps, this works and was tested

Comment: The error said the type [String] has no subscript members

Comment: Sorry you are trying to remove all section or an individual cell?

Comment: an individual cell. A selected cell.

Comment: @Rinier hello. It seems to be working correctly at first, but since data saved in the data is userdefault and it is not actually deleted completely. I attempted to write code whcih is var data = getData()
            data.remove(at: sections[indexPath.section].words[indexPath.row])
            . However, an error says [String]! has no subscript members. How can I delte userdefault data in cell?

Comment: Are you saving this on NSUserDefault?, I think that you need is make 2 methods one for saving and one for loading this data from NSUserDefault, then when you remove you save the data

Comment: Could you show me an example? I saw some posts and it seems like I need to put my userdefaults data into NSMutableArray.. But I just have no idea what to deal with this.